# combine multiple jquery scipts/funtions in one file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I normally combine my jquery functions in one file/document ready. Recently i downloaded a theme i saw some code i don't understand why it's there. I concerns the

```
if (!!$.prototype.scrollUp) {
    $.scrollUp();
}
```

part. Can someone tell me why it is there on several places? Shouldn't it work without it?

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Video Lightbox */
    if (!!$.prototype.simpleLightboxVideo) {
        $('.video').simpleLightboxVideo();
    }

    /*ScrollUp*/
    if (!!$.prototype.scrollUp) {
        $.scrollUp();
    }

    /*Responsive Navigation*/
    $("#nav-mobile").html($("#nav-main").html());
    $("#nav-trigger span").on("click",function() {
        if ($("nav#nav-mobile ul").hasClass("expanded")) {
            $("nav#nav-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        } else {
            $("nav#nav-mobile ul").addClass("expanded").slideDown(250);
            $(this).addClass("open");
        }
    });

    $("#nav-mobile").html($("#nav-main").html());
    $("#nav-mobile ul a").on("click",function() {
        if ($("nav#nav-mobile ul").hasClass("expanded")) {
            $("nav#nav-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
            $("#nav-trigger span").removeClass("open");
        }
    });

    /* Sticky Navigation */
    if (!!$.prototype.stickyNavbar) {
        $('#header').stickyNavbar();
    }

    $('#content').waypoint(function (direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            $('#header').addClass('nav-solid fadeInDown');
        }
        else {
            $('#header').removeClass('nav-solid fadeInDown');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: `!!` just forces the value to be a boolean.  Given that for it to work, the truthyness of the value after it would have to be correct, it would most likely work without it.  It's most likely programmer preference from the creator.

Comment: !! turns value to be bool value. check if (!!$.prototype.scrollUp) is to check if method exists, if 'yes' turn result into a bool value

Answer (score 0):

These are there to prevent null pointer exceptions on pages where these elements/references don't exist. Just like @Taplar commented, your pages would most likely work without them, but the console may have several warnings or errors.